# Why will GPU usage run low in NN training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm running a NN training on my GPU with pytorch.
But the GPU usage is strangely "limited" at about 50-60%.
That's a waste of computing resources but I can't make it a bit higher.

I'm sure that the hardware is fine because running 2 of my process at the same time,or training a simple NN (DCGAN,for instance) can both occupy 95% or more GPU.(which is how it supposed to be)
My NN contains several convolution layers and it should use more GPU resources.

Besides, I guess that the data from dataset has been feeding fast enough,because I used workers=64 in my dataloader instance and my disk works just fine.

I just confused about what is happening.

Dev details:

GPU : Nvidia GTX 1080 Ti

os:Ubuntu 64-bit

Comment: Did you increase batch size and still see the same usage?

Comment: try using profiler

Comment: @UmangGupta Just now I tried so.The Usage began floating between 74%-85% ,sometimes it reaches 90+%.Not sure whether a much larger batch would stop the usage floating.that's not the solution I expected but still helpful,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess without further research but it could be that your network is small in terms of layer-size (**not** number of layers) so each step of the training is not enough to occupy all the GPU resources. Or at least the ratio between the data size and the transfer speed (to the gpu memory) is bad and the GPU stays idle most of the time.

tl;dr: the gpu jobs are not long enough to justify the memory transfers

Comment: My NN includes a 1*1 conv layer.Do U think that's the point?Since running 2 of my process at the same time can occupy 95% or more GPU.Do you think applying a Dataparallel-like data loader will fix this?